# How does the HIVE table format look for the given data input?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I the data in the following format

```
6856437950      11/16/2008 22:36:38 8204208990      1001004006044273
6715281120      11/16/2008 15:29:42 8132862237      1001004005059895
```

The Hive table i have create is the following

```
CREATE TABLE t2 (session_id STRING, date_time STRING, customer_id STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

When I load the data into the table and display the contents its shows in the following format:

```
6856437950      11/16/2008 22:36:38 8204208990      1001004006044273            NULL    NULL
6715281120      11/16/2008 15:29:42 8132862237      1001004005059895            NULL    NULL
```

It shows all the elements in the row are assigned to variable session_id and the rest date_time and customer_id are NULL.

I believe I made a mistake in FIELD TERMINATED clause but I am not sure what value to assign it for.

Comment: Check that you do not have tab characters at the end of your lines, and that your fields are actually tab delimited.  Also make your session_id an int/long.

Comment: karthik. you query is good. the problem is your input is not having proper delimiter as tab. its not exactly as tab.may be some spaces. i executed your queries taking \t as filed delim, it worked fine . plz check below . problem is "your input is not \t field delimited"

Comment: @ramisetty.vijay I do understand that i have more space than '\t' but when i change my field delimited into the exact amount of spaces i get the output like this : 6856437950
                       6715281120

Comment: @jtravaglini I do have '/n' at the end of the line. Will that influence too ?

Comment: @karthik, '\n' is the default line seperator. if your input records are each in separate line(i means it have \n by default). its not the problem. only prob here is your column separators in input

Comment: you can have some alternative in this case use :SerDe Library:      org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe with the input.regex as your input record line format

Answer (score 0):

hive (default)> CREATE TABLE t2 (session_id STRING, date_time STRING, customer_id STRING)

> ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
>   FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
>   STORED AS TEXTFILE;
>   OK
>   Time taken: 9.343 seconds

hive (default)> desc t2;
OK
col_name    data_type   comment
session_id  string
date_time   string
customer_id string
Time taken: 0.319 seconds

hive (default)> LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/tmp/input.txt' INTO table t2;
Copying data from file:/tmp/input.txt
Copying file: file:/tmp/input.txt
Loading data to table default.t2
OK
Time taken: 0.766 seconds
hive (default)> select * from t2;
OK

```
session_id  date_time   customer_id
6856437950  11/16/2008 22:36:38 8204208990  1001004006044273
6715281120  11/16/2008 15:29:42 8132862237  1001004005059895
```

Time taken: 0.494 seconds
hive (default)